# Can Azure web projects (.ccproj) be opened in Visual Studio running on Windows XP?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, windows-xp

When I try to open a .ccproj file in Visual Studio 2010, running on Windows XP, I get the error:

```
<ProjectName> cannot be opened because its project type (.ccproj) is not supported by this version of the application.
```

I did some research and found that "Windows Azure Tools" needs to be installed before this will work.

However, when I tried to run the installer (which I downloaded from [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sdk/#)) I got the following message:

```
The product you are trying to install is not supported on your operating system.
```

Does this mean that it's not possible to run an Azure web project on Windows XP at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just checked the system requirements [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=15658#system-requirements). Looks like it's only supported on Windows 7/Vista/2008.

Comment: There was a requirement for IIS7 in the SDK for the emulator to run.  I think that was the main limiting factor, but there might be other ones as well.